# Testfairy Session won't close

Tags: android, session, testfairy

Hello i'm using Testfairy to test my app and i have a huge problem.
One of the sessions won't close and it transmitting for 4 hours now.
action i already make :
1) reopen the app and close it including the service that run in background.
   -> it open another Session in test fairy and when i close the app the session closed as well. but the hold session steel a live.
2) clear all app data
3) delete the app
4) reinstall the app -> open it -> and close it. same as 1.
5) turn off the phone

i need to know how to close this session. and if no WiFi around did it transmitting on cellular data?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please email `support at testfairy.com` with a link to your build and they will take a closer look. Normally, sessions close within 10 minutes of inactivity.

I am pretty sure that by now that session has been closed, but to be 100% sure, let the support team review this with you.

Comment: It was open for a week... the test fairy support work on it 3 days. After 3 days with no success i deleted the all build.